# Checking for a win in Tic-Tac-Toe

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

Okay, so I'm about finished with my latest project, a (admittedly not very good) implementation of Tic Tac Toe in Common Lisp (the whole program available [here](http://gist.github.com/655622)), but I'm stuck on one last part; I can't figure out how to get my function that checks for a winner working. The function (and its subordinate function) look like this:

```
(defun check-for-win ()
    (cond ((is-line 1 2 3) t)
            ((is-line 1 4 7) t)
            ((is-line 1 5 9) t)
            ((is-line 2 5 8) t)
            ((is-line 3 6 9) t)
            ((is-line 3 5 7) t)
            ((is-line 4 5 6) t)
            ((is-line 7 8 9) t))
    nil)

(defun is-line (a b c)
    (let ((a (aref *board* (- a 1)))
              (b (aref *board* (- b 1)))
              (c (aref *board* (- c 1))))
        (if (and 
                  (eql a b)
                  (eql a c)
                  (eql b c))
            t
            nil)))
```

(albeit not indented so deeply), and in `(is-line)`, a, b and c will be (in a winning scenario) set to a symbol (either `:X` or `:O`). How do I get the equality checks working?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's implicit `progn` in `defun` statement, so it is evaluated in a such way:

1. statements are evaluated one after another;
2. value of last statement is returned as a function result.

In your `check-for-win` you have 2 statements: `cond` and `nil`. In accordance with `progn` evaluation rules, value of `nil` will be returned for any call, and result of `cond` will be just ignored.

Try this code:

```
(defun check-for-win ()
  (cond ((is-line 1 2 3) t)
          ((is-line 1 4 7) t)
          ((is-line 1 5 9) t)
          ((is-line 2 5 8) t)
          ((is-line 3 6 9) t)
          ((is-line 3 5 7) t)
          ((is-line 4 5 6) t)
          ((is-line 7 8 9) t)
          (:else nil)))
```

`:else` is just a keyword, and as any keyword it is evaluated to true. You can use any other keyword or just `true`. So, if no statement before gave true, the result of `cond` (and all the function) will be `nil`.

Comment: That works if you place parentheses around `:else nil`. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

*In CHECK-FOR-WIN:*

The COND is a bad choice for what it's meant to accomplish.  Think
about it: you want the function to return T if any of the IS-LINEs
return T, and NIL otherwise. Well that's pretty much the definition
of what OR does, so dump the COND and collect the IS-LINE calls in
a single OR.  You could use SOME to shorten it even more, but that
might end up being too "clever."

*In IS-LINE*

Let's take this inside-out: first, EQL is transitive, so if you know
(EQL A B) and (EQL A C), then it's redundant to test (EQL B C).

Now that IF, is absolutely unforgivable.  It is, quite literally, the same as doing

```
if (x)
  return true;
else
  return false;
```

in a braces language.  You already have the truth value you want to
return so just return that.

Finally, it's bad style to shadow variables like you are doing with
the LET.  At any rate, I would argue that by tossing one EQL you
reduce the necessity of precomputing array refs to almost nil anyway.

*In general*

The convention in Common Lisp for naming predicates (functions that
return either T or NIL) is to come up with a noun phrase that
describes what they're testing for, and tack on a "p". So I think
WINNING-POSITION-P and CELLS-MATCH-P would be better names.

I think it might be a good idea to write a function to get the content
of a board square as opposed to using AREF, since the latter exposes
details of its implementation.  Even if it's a relatively minor issue
in this case, it's a good habit to get into.

Following these suggestions would result in this code:

```
(defun winning-position-p ()
  (or (cells-match-p 1 2 3)
      (cells-match-p 1 4 7)
      (cells-match-p 1 5 9)
      (cells-match-p 2 5 8)
      (cells-match-p 3 6 9)
      (cells-match-p 3 5 7)
      (cells-match-p 4 5 6)
      (cells-match-p 7 8 9)))

(defun cells-match-p (a b c)
  (and (eql (board-ref a)
            (board-ref b))
       (eql (board-ref a)
            (board-ref c)))

(defun board-ref (cell)
  ;; Could check for errors here.
  (aref *board* (1- cell)))
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the constructive criticism. I'm really new to Lisp, and I'm still trying to wrap my head around thinking in a Lisp-y fashion, so I really appreciate you pointing those things out to me. :)

Comment: @Cirno how do I make `(setf (board-ref choice) *marker*)` work, if you don't mind?

Comment: @Andrew: you need `defsetf` ot [something similar](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/cl/Customizing-Setf.html). But this isn't trivial task - you will have to go to the lower abstraction layer - to the concept of "place". Another approach is using classes and objects, that have accessors.

Comment: I'd just simply do `(defun set-board-ref (choice item) (setf (aref *board* (1- choice)) item))` before worrying about anything as elaborate as DEFSETF forms.

Comment: @Cirno I defined that function and replaced the code with a function call, but now I get `Argument X is not a number.` when entering a number as a choice. :( I don't know what broke.

Comment: @Andrew Uh, I kinda need to see what you actually wrote to diagnose it any. fyi, CHOICE is meant to be the board square and ITEM the thing to put in it, if you didn't know that already. Probably not the best names. I don't much like typing code in comments.

Comment: @Andrew When I ran that code, I got a *backtrace* detailing what the program was doing when it crashed. It said that the cause was calling (BOARD-REF NIL) from (STALEMATE). So STALEMATE is the problem. Looking at the definition I see that you have an erroneous idea of what DOLIST does ⟨http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/macros-standard-control-constructs.html#dolist-and-dotimes⟩.

Comment: But at any rate, you want to detect a stalemate by checking that none of the board cells holds a number. Fair enough, and the simplest way to detect that is `(notany #'numberp *board*)` ⟨http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/collections.html#sequence-predicates⟩.

Comment: @Cirno I actually have that book! But in regards to the backtrace, is there anything special I have to do to enable that? Because it doesn't show up when I run it. (I'm using SBCL, by the way)

Answer (score 2):

This also fixes a few other problem areas in tandem with Andrei's fix.

First, adjust logic flow in the play() functionality.

```
;;; Play the game
(defun play (&optional switch-p)
(when switch-p (switch-player))
(check-choice (read-choice))

;;; Check if we should continue playing.
(when (and 
          (not (check-for-win)) 
          (not (stalemate)))
  (play t))


;;; Check for win FIRST (last move in possible stalemate may be a win)
(when (check-for-win)
    (format t "~a has won! " *player*)
    (if (y-or-n-p "Play again? ")
        (play-again)
        (quit)))

;;; Check for stalemate.
(when (stalemate)
    (if (y-or-n-p "~%~%Stalemate! Play again? ")
        (play-again)
        (quit))))
```

Second, adjust the check-choice() function...

```
;;; Changed (> choice 1) to (> choice 0) otherwise square 1 is always invalid.
(defun check-choice (choice)
(if (and
          (numberp choice)
          (> choice 0)
          (< choice 10))
    (select choice)
    (progn
        (format t "~%Invalid choice.~%")
        (check-choice (read-choice)))))
```

The problem on the first section was that if the last move which was the only move left and a winning move the program would report a stalemate before a win.

The issue in the second section was that square 1 was always reporting an invalid selection because of it was not greater than itself.

Answer (score 1):

Take advantage of the power of first class functions and eliminate the code repetition (this has the side effect of fixing the original problem too :)

```
(defun check-for-win ()
  (some (lambda (x) (apply #'is-line x)
        '((1 2 3) (1 4 7) (1 5 9) (2 5 8) (3 6 9) (3 5 7) (4 5 6) (7 8 9))))
```

Regarding `setf`ing `board-ref`, this common case is actually rather simple,

```
(defun (setf board-ref) (val cell)
  (setf (aref *board* (1- cell)) val))
```